# Problemas en orden de campos al aplicar GROUP BY SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo este script

```
SELECT 
 No
,Fecha
,Capital
,Interes
FROM Tabla
WHERE Credito='45784346'
```

que me arroja el siguiente resultado ordenado

```
No   Fecha     CAPITAL       INTERES
1   2020-09-19  0.00        98705.37
2   2020-10-19  0.00        105755.75
3   2020-11-19  0.00        105755.75
4   2020-12-19  0.00        105755.75
5   2021-01-19  48048.64    105755.75
6   2021-02-19  48589.19    105215.20
7   2021-03-19  49135.82    104668.57
8   2021-04-19  49688.59    104115.80
9   2021-05-19  50247.59    103556.80
10  2021-06-19  50812.88    102991.51
```

Pero al agregar un campo mas **Total Cuota** que es la suma de Capital+Interes, y colocar un GroupBy me lo desordena

Script:

```
SELECT 
 No
,Fecha
,Capital
,Interes
,Sum(Capital)+Sum(Interes) As "Total Cuota"
FROM Tabla
WHERE Credito='45784346'
GROUP BY  No,Fecha,Capital,Interes
```

Me muestra este resultado

```
No    FECHA     CAPITAL      INTERES    TOTAL CUOTA
1   2020-09-19  0.00        98705.37    98705.37
10  2021-06-19  50812.88    102991.51   153804.39
100 2028-12-19  139072.70   14731.69    153804.39
101 2029-01-19  140637.27   13167.12    153804.39
102 2029-02-19  142219.44   11584.95    153804.39
103 2029-03-19  143819.41   9984.98     153804.39
104 2029-04-19  145437.38   8367.01     153804.39
105 2029-05-19  147073.55   6730.84     153804.39
106 2029-06-19  148728.13   5076.26     153804.39
107 2029-07-19  150401.32   3403.07     153804.39
```

Porque sucede esto?
Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: ¿Por que necesitas el `GROUP BY`? En el ejemplo inicial, no hay nada que sea necesario agrupar. Si lo que necesitas es la suma de dos campos entonces obtenela `Capital + Interes AS 'Total Cuota'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La columna `No` parece definida como un texto. (varchar/nvarchar).

Y la está ordenando como tal.

```
Create Table dbo.tablaEjemplo
             (
             No      varchar(10)
           , Fecha   date
           , CAPITAL decimal(8, 2)
           , INTERES decimal(8, 2)
             );
Insert into dbo.tablaEjemplo
Values
('1'   ,'2020-09-19',0.00      ,  98705.37 ),
('2'   ,'2020-10-19',0.00      ,  105755.75),
('3'   ,'2020-11-19',0.00      ,  105755.75),
('4'   ,'2020-12-19',0.00      ,  105755.75),
('5'   ,'2021-01-19',48048.64  ,  105755.75),
('6'   ,'2021-02-19',48589.19  ,  105215.20),
('7'   ,'2021-03-19',49135.82  ,  104668.57),
('8'   ,'2021-04-19',49688.59  ,  104115.80),
('9'   ,'2021-05-19',50247.59  ,  103556.80),
('10'  ,'2021-06-19',50812.88  ,  102991.51);
```

Por esto es muy importante poner la definición de las tablas en las preguntas, ya que los comportamientos del motor en función del tipo de columna, pueden ser diferentes.

La solución pasa por convertir esa columna a entero, en el momento de la ordenación.

```
SELECT 
 No
,Fecha
,Capital
,Interes
,Sum(Capital)+Sum(Interes) As "Total Cuota"
FROM dbo.tablaEjemplo
--WHERE Credito='45784346'
GROUP BY  No,Fecha,Capital,Interes
Order by try_Cast(No as int), fecha;
```

[image: Res]

He usado `try_Cast` para asegurar que la consulta no falla, si hay un valor en `No`, que no sea numérico. Caso de que ocurra esto, te salrá la primera.

```
Insert into dbo.tablaEjemplo
Values
('1-a'   ,'2020-09-19',0.00      ,  98705.37 );
```

[image: res2]

Answer (score 2):

No se puede afirmar que los datos se desordenan, porque en el modelo relacional  los datos NO tienen un orden definido. El motor de base de datos que utilices puede devolverte los resultados en un orden arbitrario a menos que incluyas una cláusula `order by` como parte de la consulta.

De hecho, el orden del resultado puede variar entre una ejecución y otra de la misma consulta, aunque no es usual que ocurra, no puedes asumir ningún orden particular a menos que lo  especifíques explícitamente.

En ese caso, el motor debe respetar el orden que solicitas y entregarte los resultados según las reglas de los tipos de dato de las columnas incluidas en dicha cláusula y en orden ascendente o descendente según se solicite o en orden ascendente si no se indica nada explícitamente.

Agrega al final de tu consulta un ordenamiento que incluya cualquier combinación de columnas del resultado, por ejemplo, para ver los datos en orden cronológico, podrías incluir:

```
order by Fecha
```

O para verlas ordenadas por número

```
order by No
```